# JPA 2.1 does not insert rows from .sql file even when specifying it in persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, hsqldb, jpa-2.1

I am trying to insert into a HSQL database from a sql file. I tried following this tutorial https://antoniogoncalves.org/2014/12/11/generating-database-schemas-with-jpa-2-1/
It doesnt load my rows from sql file. I am not sure where i am going wrong. please help. My files are:

persistence.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <description>JPA Test</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.jpa.entity.Person</class>
    <properties>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:unittests" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source"
            value="import.sql" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

import.sql

```
    insert into table Person(person_ID, person_name, age) values(101, "Name1", 30 );
    insert into Person(person_ID, person_name, age) values(102, "Name2", 30 );
```

Person.java

```
    package com.jpa.entity;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="Person")
    public class Person {

@Id
@Column(name="person_ID")
private int id;

@Column(name="person_name")
private String name;

@Column(name="age")
private int age;

//generated public getters and setters
```

DemoJPA.java

```
    package com.jpa.demo;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.persistence.Persistence;

    import com.jpa.entity.Person;
    public class DemoJPA {

private static final EntityManagerFactory emf;
static{

    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
}
public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Persistence.generateSchema("persistenceUnit", null);
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();  
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Person f = new Person();
    f.setId(1);
    f.setName("Name1");
    f.setAge(29);
    em.persist(f);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.clear();
    System.out.println("Done");

        }
    }
```

My folder structure is:
[folderStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fg3z.png)

pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org        /xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.jpa.entity</groupId>
      <artifactId>JPA2Project</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
          <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.7.5</log4j.version>
    </properties>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
          <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
     </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Comment: It seems like you have an error in your import file. First row is "insert into table ..." but should be "insert into ..."

Comment: I assumed it would throw a sqlexception since there is an error in insert. I removed it. it still doesnt pickup the sql file

Comment: have you tried setting the path relative to src folder? like 'main/resources/import.sql'

Comment: yes. I tried that.it doesnt do anything. are my settings for picking up the file correct? should i also be adding some other technology to help JPA get the file

Comment: Usually, the initial load script to generate the schema (or) insert the data will be kept under META-INF/ folder, and loaded from xml as 'META-INF/import.sql' file. Refer the project https://github.com/hantsy/ee7-sandbox/wiki/jpa-scripts

Comment: @K139 from the link, it looks like i need to have sql files for creating and deleting tables. it also looks like the project uses eclipselink. I tried using hibernate too like this: `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="import.sql" /> ` isnt it possible to just have the import data script without create and delete scripts

Comment: @K139 I tried adding the sql to META-INF and referencing it that way. It doesnt seem to work for me that way

Comment: I may assume that script execution steps accomplishes earlier that you generate schema (according to doc it's an application load time). Try to generate schema using script also - https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro005.htm

Comment: Thanks @K139 for the link. it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In the `persistence.xml` file, I added the following code in properties tag at the end:

```
    <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="metadata"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="import.sql"/>
```

`import.sql` file is located in `src/main/resources` folder. We can also place it in the `META-INF` folder and reference it as `META-INF/import.sql`,
also I edited the `import.sql` with the correct query.
This code to be used if we need models i.e. @Entity(aka metadata) to manage the database schema.

Comment: My problem was that I also specified the property `eclipselink.ddl-generation`, because of that the `javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source` was ignored.